# Centering a text box in align with an image and other textboxes

Tags: html, css

I've reached an obstacle I can't seem the get through in my `styles.css`. I'm re-creating a Google homepage, and for some reason cannot get the search bar to become centered in the page.

I've tried doing `margin: auto 0;`, `border-left: 200px;`, `text-align: center;`, but the search bar will not move (I put this within `.searchbar .search`).

```css
.googlelogo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #696969;
}

.nav .nav-left .about,
.nav .nav-right .gmail {
  padding: 10px;
}

.searchbar .search {
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 400px;
}

.searchbuttons {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  float: center;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  margin-right: 6.5px;
  margin-left: 6.5px;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 240px;
  width: 98%;
}

.footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #696969;
}

.footer .footer-left .advertising,
.footer .footer-left .business,
.footer .footer-left .howsearchworks {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.footer .footer-right .privacy,
.footer .footer-right .terms,
.footer .footer-right .settings {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href='/styles/styles.css' text='styles/css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <title>Google</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='nav'>
    <div class='nav-left'>
      <a class='about' href='www.google.com/#'>About</a>
      <a class='store' href='www.google.com/#'>Store</a>
    </div>
    <div class='nav-right'>
      <a class='images' href='www.google.com/#'>Images</a>
      <a class='gmail' href='www.google.com/#'>Gmail</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='logo'>
    <img class='googlelogo' src='http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c51f.png' alt='Google logo' height='250'>
  </div>
  <div class='searchbar'>
    <form>
      <input class='search' type='text'>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class='searchbuttons'>
    <form>
      <button class='button' label='Google Search'>Google Search</button>
      <button class='button' label="I'm Feeling Lucky">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'>
    <div class='footer-left'>
      <a class='advertising' href='www.google.com/#'>Advertising</a>
      <a class='business' href='www.google.com/#'>Business</a>
      <a class='howsearchworks' href='www.google.com/#'>How Search works</a>
    </div>
    <div class='footer-right'>
      <a class='privacy' href='www.google.com/#'>Privacy</a>
      <a class='terms' href='www.google.com/#'>Terms</a>
      <a class='settings' href='www.google.con/#'>Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

How can I get the search bar to become centered and aligned on the screen (formatted so it's above the two buttons below and below the Google logo)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class='searchbar'>
    <form style="text-align: center">
      <input class='search' type='text'>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Oh, I think I was modifying my input class, not the actual form. Thanks! I assume to move the box up, I would have to add a padding to the form?

Comment: Yes, you can treat `form` like a `div` and style it just the same way you'd style a `div`. Alternatively, you can open your `form` tag further up the node chain, and nest a bunch of `div`s inside it. Either way should work fine. Form's default `display` mode is `block`, which is the same as `div`, so you can style them similarly.

Answer (score 1):

**Added this**

```css
.searchbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```css
.googlelogo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #696969;
}

.nav .nav-left .about,
.nav .nav-right .gmail {
  padding: 10px;
}

.searchbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.searchbar .search {
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 400px;
}

.searchbuttons {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  float: center;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  margin-right: 6.5px;
  margin-left: 6.5px;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 240px;
  width: 98%;
}

.footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #696969;
}

.footer .footer-left .advertising,
.footer .footer-left .business,
.footer .footer-left .howsearchworks {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.footer .footer-right .privacy,
.footer .footer-right .terms,
.footer .footer-right .settings {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href='/styles/styles.css' text='styles/css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <title>Google</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='nav'>
    <div class='nav-left'>
      <a class='about' href='www.google.com/#'>About</a>
      <a class='store' href='www.google.com/#'>Store</a>
    </div>
    <div class='nav-right'>
      <a class='images' href='www.google.com/#'>Images</a>
      <a class='gmail' href='www.google.com/#'>Gmail</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='logo'>
    <img class='googlelogo' src='http://assets.stickpng.com/thumbs/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c51f.png' alt='Google logo' height='250'>
  </div>
  <div class='searchbar'>
    <form>
      <input class='search' type='text'>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class='searchbuttons'>
    <form>
      <button class='button' label='Google Search'>Google Search</button>
      <button class='button' label="I'm Feeling Lucky">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'>
    <div class='footer-left'>
      <a class='advertising' href='www.google.com/#'>Advertising</a>
      <a class='business' href='www.google.com/#'>Business</a>
      <a class='howsearchworks' href='www.google.com/#'>How Search works</a>
    </div>
    <div class='footer-right'>
      <a class='privacy' href='www.google.com/#'>Privacy</a>
      <a class='terms' href='www.google.com/#'>Terms</a>
      <a class='settings' href='www.google.con/#'>Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```